# React useRef is not setting even in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

I am attempting to show an image in a random position according to dynamic dimensions using a ref. However, when getting the useRef's current value, I recieve undefined likely because the useRef's target div hasn't loaded yet.

To overcome this, I am using a useEffect to wait for the target div to load.

However, when I run the program the image does not move because the useRef's current value remains at 0. The

```
import './MouseAim.css'
import '../Game.css'

import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'

import TargetImg from '../../../assets/Target.png'
import _ from "lodash";

function MouseAim() {
    const [start, setStart] = useState(true)
    const [target, setTarget] = useState(true)
    const elementDimensions = useRef()


    //wait for elementDimensions to be set
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('elementDimensions', elementDimensions.current?.clientHeight)
    } , [elementDimensions])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="main-container">
                {
                        start ?

                            <div ref={elementDimensions} className="aim-container">
                                {
                                    target ?
                                            <input 
                                                className="target" 
                                                type="image" 
                                                style={{position: "relative", left:elementDimensions.current?.clientHeight+"px" , top:_.random(0, elementDimensions.current?.clientHeight)+"px"}}
                                                onClick={() => console.log("hello")} 
                                                src={TargetImg} 
                                                alt="target"
                                            />
                                    :null
                                }
                            </div>

                        :
                            <div className="start-container">
                                <input className="start-button" type="button" value="Start Game" onClick={() => setStart(true)}/>
                            </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MouseAim
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your target initial state to 'false', then set it to true when 'ref' is ready

Try this one:

```
const [start, setStart] = useState(true)
const [target, setTarget] = useState(false)
const elementDimensions = useRef()


//wait for elementDimensions to be set
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('elementDimensions', elementDimensions.current?.clientHeight)
    setTarget(true)
} , [elementDimensions])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you mentioned, the useRef is set very initially when the div has not been mounted.

The div mounts when `start` becomes true. So that's where the trigger needs to happen.

Try to pass `start` as the dependency variables to the `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('elementDimensions', elementDimensions.current?.clientHeight)
    } , [start, elementDimensions])
```

PS. If it doesn't work, pass `target` as the dependency variable as well.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('elementDimensions', elementDimensions.current?.clientHeight)
    } , [start, target, elementDimensions])
```

Comment: Hey good point! I will change this in my code as it makes sense. Sadly both solutions did not work.

Comment: Why are you using useRef to change the value dynamically?
What logic are you planning to implement?

Comment: Well, I looked it up and in order to get the dimensions of my dynamic element, I need to use a useRef. Do you know of a better way? (My logic is to generate a random x and y pos for my target/button in the bounds of the div. If the user clicks on the button it will generate a new x and y pos in the bounds of the div.)

Answer (score 0):

I think separating your code into subcomponents will make this much simpler, as `MouseAim` has too much responsibility. In general, giving your components one clearly-defined purpose is a good way to simplify your codebase.

```js
const AimContainer = () => {
    const containerRef = useRef()
    const [containerSize, setContainerSize] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        // set container size state here
    }, [])

    return <div ref={containerRef}>...</div>
}

const MouseAim = () => {
    const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false);

    return <div>
        { hasStarted ? 
            <AimContainer />
            :
            <button onClick={() => setHasStarted(true)}>Start</button>
        }
    </div>

}
```

`AimContainer` will render before running `useEffect`, so you may also want to avoid rendering the target until `containerSize` is set.